# Laravel subdomain .htaccess // error 500 (Wedos)

Tags: php, laravel, apache, .htaccess, subdomain

**I've tried every solution here. My problem is my shared webhosting provider has blocked MultiViews.**

My main domain build with laravel works ( liated.cz ) but my subdomain keeps giving me errors 500 / 403 or infinite loop, it depends which .htaccess i write

**Structure:**

**www**

-----domains

--------------liated.cz // Works

--------------testing.liated.cz // Errors

-----subdomains

***In subdomains the laravel never works thats a common issue at my provider ( Wedos ), anyway you can put your subdomain in domains folder.***

**Laravel :**

testing.liated.cz

--------------public

---------------------index.php // Here i need to go.

**!! without !!**

```
The .htaccess CAN'T contain 

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
            Options -MultiViews -Indexes
        </IfModule>
```

**My .htaccess in domains/testing.liated.cz**

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^testing.liated.cz$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.testing.liated.cz$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/public/
RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1 [L]
```

**My .htaccess in domains/testing.liated.cz/public**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

When i remove Options +FollowSymLinks i get an infinite loop which crashes.
Im very desperate, in future I must change my provider i'm tired of this, 2 days loosing time with .htaccess.

**Hope someone can help. Thanks in advance.**

*The laravel application works, i tried a free shared provider and it gives no errors.*

**EDIT**

***.htaccess in root***

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

***.htaccess in public***

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Now I cant reach to testing.liated.cz/

But i can reach testing.liated/admin or testing.liated/admin/gallery

So what :]

Comment: What's the content of the logs if the 500 error occurs?

Comment: Can't access the logs, its a paid service, my provider is a motherf****.

Comment: FollowSymLinks is a _requirement_ for mod_rewrite to work. MultiViews usually only comes into play, when you are rewriting stuff with partial overlaps between the made-up path, and actually existing files - say, rewriting `/products/123` to `products.php?id=123`. Can you be a bit more specific as to what exactly is not working, which example URLs? Can’t access the subdomain at all, not even the root? Or is it specific URLs below that?

Comment: Can't access even the root, i've managed to access testing.liated.cz/admin/login, but  only for a period of time then i changed i and i dont remember the .htaccess for it. 2 days ago I used some htaccess and all was working, then i downloaded the project, changed .htaccess to work on localhost and then its not working, i set permissions to file, this should not be the problem.

Comment: Maybe try _enabling_ MultiViews on your local dev setup then, to try and reproduce the conditions on the live server - and then check what the log files have to say.

Comment: Can't get error 500 on local dev. Disabled, enabled MultiViews. Or maybe im not doing it right, i use xamp.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but now it works with these setups, also i have in .env wrote the url testing.liated.cz. Hope this can help someone in future.

**.htaccess in root**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**.htaccess in public**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```